# Multi-dimensional can't hover to 2nd menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multi-dimensional drop-down menu. but it can't hover to the 2nd level menu. it will disappear as moveout from the 1st level menu. how to keep 2nd level menu when mouseover from the 1st level menu?

```
var lvcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('lvcontainer');
var rvcontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('rvcontainer');

for (i = 0; i < lvcontainer.length; i++) {  // loop to the length
  (function(protectedIndex) {               // protect the index so clicks won't use last increment of i

    // show
    lvcontainer[protectedIndex].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
      rvcontainer[protectedIndex].style.display = "block"; 
    }, false);

    // hide
    lvcontainer[protectedIndex].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
      rvcontainer[protectedIndex].style.display = "none";
    }, false);
  })(i);
}
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: auto;
}

#container {
  display: table;
}

#lcontainer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

#rcontainer {
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.rvcontainer {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="lcontainer">
    <div class="lvcontainer">
      Country
    </div>
    <div class="lvcontainer">
      Genre
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rcontainer">
    <div class="rvcontainer">
      Japan
      <br> Korea
      <br> American
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="rvcontainer">
      Comedy
      <br> Mystery
      <br> Horror
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above code, rvcontainer will disappear if mouseout from lvcontainer. how to keep lvcontainer and rvcontainer when mouseover to rvcontainer? CSS solution more welcome.

Comment: Does this have to be a javascript solution? Because this can be easily done with only CSS, but I don't want to post that as an answer unless that will help you.

Comment: @ecg8 i prefer css but my previous post no one can answer in css. i try to selector `.lvcontainer:hover + .rvcontainer` but don't work.